# sas--deal with missing values?

Tags: sas, missing-data

Here is the original data:

```
data new;
input id a b c;
cards;
1 41 . .
1 . 42 .
1 . . 43
;
run;
```

How can I get the output like this?

```
id a b c
1 41 42 43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First read as is and then use the UPDATE trick below.

```
Data want;
update new(obs=0) new;
by ID;
run;
```

Another option is to summarize the data, if you take a statistic on each column it will be the unique value but the update is the quickest.